# Is modeling infinite-scale relationships in NoSQL / BigTable (GAE) possible?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, entity-relationship, data-modeling, bigtable

My team is writing an application with GAE (Java) that has led me to question the scalability of entity relationship modeling (specifically many-to-many) in object oriented databases like BigTable.

The preferred solution for modeling unowned one-to-many and many-to-many relationships in the App Engine Datastore (see [Entity Relationships in JDO](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships?hl=en)) seems to be list-of-keys. However, Google warns:

> "There are a few limitations to implementing many-to-many
>   relationships this way. First, you must explicitly retrieve the values
>   on the side of the collection where the list is stored since all you
>   have available are Key objects. Another more important one is that you
>   want to avoid storing overly large lists of keys..."

Speaking of *overly large lists of keys*, if you attempt to model this way and assume that you are storing one Long for each key then with a per-entity limit of 1MB the theoretical maximum number of relationships per entity is ~130k. For a platform who's primary advantage is scalabililty, that's really not that many relationships. So now we are looking at possibly sharding entities which require more than 130k relationships.

A different approach (Relationship Model) is outlined in the article [Modeling Entity Relationships](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling) as part of the Mastering the datastore series in the AppEngine developer resources. However, even here Google warns about the performance of relational models:

> "However, you need to be very careful because traversing the
>   connections of a collection will require more calls to the datastore.
>   Use this kind of many-to-many relationship only when you really need
>   to, and do so with care to the performance of your application."

So by now you are asking: **'Why do you need more than 130k relationships per-entity?'** Well I'm glad you asked. Let's take, for example, a CMS application with say 1 million users (Hey I can dream right?!)

Users can upload content and share it with:
 1. public
 2. individuals
 3. groups
 4. any combination

Now someone logs in, and navigates to a dashboard that shows new uploads from people they are connected to in any group. This dashboard should include public content, and content shared specifically with this user or a group this user is a member of. Not too bad right? Let's dig into it.

```
public class Content {
  private Long id;
  private Long authorId;
  private List<Long> sharedWith; //can be individual ids or group ids
}
```

Now my query to get everything an id is allowed to see might look like this:

```
List<Long> idsThatGiveMeAccess = new ArrayList<Long>();
idsThatGiveMeAccess.add(myId);
idsThatGiveMeAccess.add(publicId); //Let's say that sharing with 0L makes it public
for (Group g : groupsImIn)
    idsThatGiveMeAccess.add(g.getId());

List<Long> authorIdsThatIWantToSee = new ArrayList<Long>();
//Add a bunch of authorIds

Query q = new Query("Content")
            .addFilter("authorId", Query.FilterOperator.IN, authorIdsThatIWantToSee)
            .addFilter("sharedWith", Query.FilterOperator.IN, idsThatGiveMeAccess);
```

Obviously I've already broken several rules. Namely, using two IN filters will blow up. Even a single IN filter at any size approaching the limits we are talking about would blow up. Aside from all that, let's say I want to limit and page through the results... no no! You can't do that if you use an IN filter. I can't think of any way to do this operation in a single query - which means you can't paginate it without extensive read-time processing and managing multiple cursors.

So here are the tools I can think of for doing this: denormalization, sharding, or relationship entities. However even with these concepts I don't see how it is possible to model this data in a way that could scale. Obviously it's possible. Google and others do it all the time. I just can't see how. **Can anyone shed any light on how to model this or point me toward any good resources for cms-style access control based on NoSQL DB?**

Answer (score 1):

storing a list of ids as a property wont scale.
Why not simply store a new object for each new relationship? (Like in sql).
That object will store for your cms two properties: The id of the shared item and the user id. If its shared with 1000 users you will have 1000 of these. Querying it for a given user is trivial. Listing permissions for a given item or a list of what a user has shared with them is easy too.